# bashスクリプトでネストした$()でもsetコマンドでエラー時に終了させる方法

Tags: bash, shellscript, shell

bashスクリプトで$()をネストしている場合でも`set -e`コマンドでエラー時に終了させるにはどうしたらよいでしょうか。

```sh
#!/bin/bash 

set -euC

# スクリプトがおかれているディレクトリを取得
# 実行例
# ./test.sh
# 実行結果
# test.sh: 行 19: cdd: コマンドが見つかりません
# RESULT
# /workspace


# 正しい例
SCRIPT_FILE_DIR=$(cd "$(dirname "$0")"; pwd)

# 誤った例
# cd を cdd とタイポしている
SCRIPT_FILE_DIR=$(cdd "$(dirname "$0")"; pwd)
readonly SCRIPT_FILE_DIR

echo "RESULT"
echo "$SCRIPT_FILE_DIR"
```

Comment: 終了しませんか？
どうなるのですか？

Comment: 実行結果を追加しました。

Comment: なるほど、shだと止まりますがbashだと止まらないですね。

Comment: 一案としては `trap` で exit する事が考えられます(この場合、サブシェルでも `trap` を有効化するために `set -E` が必要になりますけれども)。

Comment: 「set -euC -o posix」のようにposixオプションを追加してみるというのもありますかね(結局shで動かすのと大差ないと思うので要件に合わないかもしれませんが)

Comment: bash の POSIX モードは、POSIX に準拠しない動作を準拠させるだけで、POSIX を超える拡張機能を無効にはしないので、十分選択肢になると思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-Eオプションをsetし、ERRをトラップして明示的にexitするのはいかがでしょうか？

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -euC
set -E
trap 'exit $?' ERR

# スクリプトがおかれているディレクトリを取得
# 実行例
# ./test.sh
# 実行結果
# test.sh: 行 19: cdd: コマンドが見つかりません
# RESULT
# /workspace


# 正しい例
SCRIPT_FILE_DIR=$(cd "$(dirname "$0")"; pwd)

# 誤った例
# cd を cdd とタイポしている
SCRIPT_FILE_DIR=$(cdd "$(dirname "$0")"; pwd)
readonly SCRIPT_FILE_DIR

echo "RESULT"
echo "$SCRIPT_FILE_DIR"
```

実行するとecho "RESULT"の前にスクリプトが終了します。

```
./qw.sh: 行 21: cdd: コマンドが見つかりません
```

metropolisさんのコメントを受けて`trap 'exit $?' ERR`としました。
`$?`がtrapで指定したコマンドに引き継げることも確認しました。

Comment: exit status を `1` に決め打ちしていますが、サブシェルの exit status を使う方が適切でしょう。`trap 'exit $?' ERR`

Answer (score 2):

これはコマンド置換の中に `set -e` (errexit) の効果が継承されないという問題です。POSIX に準拠した動作ではないので（bash 2.05.0 以上であれば） `set -o posix` もしくは POSIX モード（`sh`）で起動することによって解決します。また bash 4.4 以上であれば `shopt -s inherit_errexit` でこの問題だけを個別に POSIX に準拠させることができます。

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e
shopt -s inherit_errexit # または set -o posix

output=$(no-such-a-command; echo ok)
echo "end: $output" # ここにはこない
```

その他の解決策としてはコマンド置換の中で `set -e` を再有効化することでも解決することができます。

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e

output=$(set -e; no-such-a-command; echo ok)
echo "end: $output" # ここにはこない
```